# Cannot find nodes / elements with event tag with xpath

Tags: python, events, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

On [this](https://www.npr.org/2018/10/17/658092462/dont-be-fooled-by-the-talking-horse-bojack-is-a-sadness-sneak-attack) page I want to get the link to download the audio (on the left side).

Unfortunately it seems I cannot select anything at all with xpath except `main`, so

```
from lxml import html
import requests as r

p = r.get(<url>)
t = html.fromstring(p.text)
t.xpath('//main')
```

returns `[<Element main ...]`

But if I call `t.xpath('//main/div')` an empty list is returned.

I'm guessing this has to do with the `event` tag that the div has (so something javascript related)? If yes is there a way to get around it?

Comment: I see "Data Protection Choices" page when navigating to shared URL. That's might be a problem

Comment: Ah! So it sees me as a new visitor when I'm calling it like that and is showing a different page. Interesting!

Comment: Yeah. When you do a single request, server knows nothing about you and your history

Comment: how could I tell it about myself? I'm guessing providing a header is not enough?

Comment: You might need to create `requests.session()` and make second request with cookies from first one. Also as I can see additional parameter `t` (don't know what it is) should be passed